# Resetting mysql integer value

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table name Order_Ticket_Number as following:

```
CREATE TABLE order_ticket_number ( 
    id_store_ticket int(10) NOT NULL,
    id_order_ticket int(3) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_date_order timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    id_order int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_store_ticket,id_order_ticket,id_date_order) 
)
ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to restart the value of `id_order_ticket` each time I open a store from the Python application I am developing. id_order_ticket is starting with 001, 002 ... and I want every day to start with 001 when I am making **SOD(start-of-day)**. There will be not conflict to have two time `ex.id_order_ticket = 001` because id_date_order is also `PK and Engine=myisam.`
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you need to change the order of columns in the primary key and use a `DATE` column, not timestamp:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id_store_ticket, id_date, id_order_ticket)
```

Example, tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0329f/1)**:

```
CREATE TABLE order_ticket_number 
  ( id_store_ticket int(10) NOT NULL,
    id_date DATE NOT NULL,
    id_order_ticket int(3) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_date_order timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    id_order int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  

   PRIMARY KEY (id_store_ticket, id_date, id_order_ticket)
  )                                    
  ENGINE = MyISAM ;
```

Dates cannot have a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property, so yuo have to ensure that the date and timestamp columns have consistent values.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know it would increment based on the primary key.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: This only works in MyISAM though so it's of no use if you want DRI and transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql documentation states that it is impossible:

> To change the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to be used for new
>   rows, do this:
>
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value; You cannot reset the counter to
>   a value less than or equal to any that have already been used.

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)